# POSTing json to express using jQuery

Tags: json, node.js, post, express

I'm having an issue when sending JSON data from my client to a node server running express.

Here's a simple server that demonstrates my issue:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){   
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.logger());
});

app.listen(80);

app.post('/', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.number + 1);
});
```

This server simply logs all POST data to the console.

If I then paste the following into chrome's development console:
`$.post('/', {number:1});`

The server prints out:

```
{ number: '1' }
11
```

How can I stop the number I'm passing being interpreted as a string?
Is it something to do with the bodyParser middleware I'm using?

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`$.post` sends url-encoded data, so what is really sent is `number=1`, which then is parsed as well as it can by bodyParser middleware.

To send json you have to use `JSON.stringify({number:1})`.

Using `$.post` unfortunately won't set the appropriate `Content-Type` header (express will handle it anyway), so it's better to use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/', 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    data: JSON.stringify({number:1})}
)
```

Comment: And don't forget to add the contentType: 'application/json' header or there will be no data in req.body at the server at all.

Comment: @soulcheck can you please look at my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085674/send-object-to-nodejs-using-post-method it's similar to this one but i need to send another property with the array

Comment: Christiaan Westerbeek's comment on the money. Don't confuse json: true with contentType: 'application/json'. Not the same thing. Add contentType: 'application/json' if you want it to work.