# How to Send Firebase token from client side and receive it in server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I want to send the user token generated by firebase on client side to server. How do I do this?

I have been able to generate the token on the client side and attempted to POST it to server but I keep getting internal server error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

client side code

```
        firebase.auth().currentUser
            .getIdToken()
            .then(function (token) {
              console.log(token)
                accessToken = token;


            });

            var mydata = {
              customToken: accessToken
            }

             $.post('/auth',mydata, function(data, status){

                      console.log(data+" and status is "+ status)

             })
```

server.js code

```
app.post('/auth', function(req, res){

  var token = req.body

  res.render(token)



})
```

I want to be able to read the token in /auth. What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

You should put the request inside of **then function**:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(function (token) {
   console.log(token)
   var mydata = {
     customToken: accessToken
   }

   /* $.post('/auth',mydata, function(data, status){
       console.log(data.token + " and status is " + status)
   }) */
   // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498256/posting-json-to-express-using-jquery
   // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice
   $.ajax({
      url: '/auth',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.token)
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.error(errorThrown) }
  })
})
```

Firebase getIdToken returns a Promise, so the code is async. Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise

The server should use **firebase-admin** package to verify token. Sample setup:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
let serviceAccount = null

try {
  // download serviceAccount.json from Firebase
  serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json')
  admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: FIREBASE_DB_PATH
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.error('An error has occurred configuring Firebase')
}
```

And remember to parse the JSON body request in express:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

...express config...

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Then you can access the token:

```
app.post('/auth', async (req, res) => {
  /* if you are using node >= 10 use the line below,
     but use this: const token = req.body.customToken */
  const { customToken: token } = req.body
  let decodedToken = null
  // For example check token
  try { 
     decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
  } catch (err) {
     console.error('Error trying to verify the token: ' + err)
     return res.status(403).json({ message: err.message })
  }

  return res.status(200).json({ token: decodedToken })
})
```

You should check this link https://medium.com/@yaniv_g/dont-use-bodyparser-json-with-jquery-post-d034c44ac7ad

Comment: I got this error                                                                        " UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `customToken` of 'undefined' or 'null'."

Comment: If you got this error on the server side, then try to check first your node version (node >= 10 is required for the code I wrote here), and check what is req.body reciving, using `console.log(util.inspects(req.body))`. You can change this line `const { customToken: token } = req.body` to `const token = req.body.customToken`. If you got this error on the server side, add catch to inspect better the error: `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(function (token) { /* same code */ }).catch(function (err) { console.error('Error processing token: ' + err) }), and check again.

Comment: And check how to send using jQuery POST to express: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498256/posting-json-to-express-using-jquery. I edited the answer to fix that. Using $.post unfortunately won't set the appropriate Content-Type header (express will handle it anyway), so it's better to use: `.ajax({
    url: '/auth', 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
    success: function (data) { console.log(data.token) }
)`